# Is 欢 a result complement of 喜 in the morphological breakdown of 喜欢？

Tags: etymology

Can somebody break down 喜欢 for me?

喜 alone is defined as a verb, "to be fond of"，so I imagine that this is the sense of the the word that is used in the compound 喜欢, which means the same thing.

欢 is defined as an adjective, which of course is a kind of verb in Chinese, "to be jolly, to be merry".

So can I think of 欢 as a resultative complement of 喜？To be fond of something resulting in one's own jolliness/merriment?

---

I know that 喜欢 is a word, not a phrase. I am looking for the original phrase that gave rise to the word, ie a morphological analysis of the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it's not. 欢 and 喜 are synonymous adjectives that are juxtaposed to form a verb.

1. At the beginning, they were two synonyms that are often used together.
2. Then it becomes a habit. 欢喜 and 喜欢 were used interchangeably, with the meaning *happy, joyful*.

As a word, both 欢喜 and 喜欢 are first documented in Han Dynasty.

> 伐纣时士卒欢喜，奋迅急速，以尚威势，猛而不倾侧也。 （西汉）《史记》
>
> 知其安危问养，视其复闻小善言，心为之喜欢，是孝之所致也。（东汉）《太平经》

欢喜 is, however, more frequently used, especially in the translation of Buddhist scriptures.

3. Mostly, 欢喜 retains the meaning of *happy*, but in some examples, standing alone, it's difficult to determine whether it's "happy" or "to like", such as

> 便行则人人欢喜，不动则个个生嫌。（宋）《五灯会元》

In （明）《拍案惊奇》, the meanings are both associated with 喜欢.

> 满生心里喜欢道：“谁想绝处逢生，遇着这等好人。”  happy
>
> 小人喜欢他妻子。  like

It's clear if an object is followed, since an adjective cannot have an object. It has to be a verb, meaning *to like*.

If there's no explict object, it's sometimes hard to decide:

> 我见他是路歧人，不喜欢。

From this, a logical development of the semantics of 喜欢 could be as follows: as a compound adjective 喜欢 first extends from *happy* to *liking*, then it changes part of speech to include the transitive verb *to like*. In many dialects and also the common tongue, 喜欢 has lost the meaning of *happy*, while 欢喜 only retains that meaning.

Notably in Wu Chinese, 喜欢 and 欢喜 still have the same meaning, with 喜欢 being formal and not usually used colloquially.

Answer (score 0):

喜 is a verb - "to be fond of", "to like", or "to enjoy"

欢 is an adjective indicating "a state of mind" - "joyous", "pleased", or "happy".

喜 is a verb but can't be used alone, it needs a supplement. Combined with 欢, it becomes a compound "verb" that means "like", as in "I like!", or a "transitive verb", as in "I like **it**!", and "I am fond of (**something** - an object)".

So - "can I think of 欢 as a resultative complement of 喜"? "**YES**, it is a case of "result complement".

Comment: This doesn't answer my question -- it simply restates the information that I already provided.